# Maintaining different URLs for different Build Configurations in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I created four different build configurations to my xcode project, they are QA, STAGING< UAT<& PRODUCTION. I use 4 different urls each for one build i created.

Now my question is xcode 4 is very good at detecting DEBUG mode as there is already predefined macro available, but How can I detect my custom builds so that i can pass different urls for different builds configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each one of those build configurations go into build settings and add a #define THIS_IS_QA=1 then test for it in your code and use it as you would use the DEBUG macro

Comment: did you mean in preprocessor macros or some where else? where exactly i should enter "#define THIS_IS_QA=1" in build settings?

Comment: same place DEBUG is defined yes

Comment: Preprocessor macros are your friend when changing settings like that for debug/release builds

Comment: ok did it in preprocessor macros. In code it gives me following error when i use  "#if THIS_IS_QA"    Unterminated conditional directive

Comment: bad syntax you need an #endif

Comment: ok thats perfect, Macros work now but i get this warning #if DEBUG

#endif THIS_IS_QA NSLOG(@"THIS IS QA");

how to get rid of this warning..
extra tokens at end of #endif directive

Comment: move the #endif after the conditional logic

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor macro route works alright and is quick to implement. But it does not scale well since you will end up with copies of each variable. The route I find works the best is to do the following.

1. Define the configuration as a User-Defined Setting in the project or target build settings.

   - Doing this allows for different values to be specified for each build configuration (eg. Debug or Release or even a custom one)
2. Create an information property in the projects plist file.

   - This allows the build setting to be accessed through the plist.
3. Write the code once to load the value form the plist file.

Example:

In the project create a User-Defined Setting called "BASE_API_URL" and set the debug configuration to "http://www.test.example.com" and the release configuration to "http://www.example.com".

Then in the plist create a new information property with the key of "BaseAPIUrl" and the value of "$(BASE_API_URL)"

Lastly in the app delegate where you define the base url add the following code:

```
let baseUrl: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["BaseAPIUrl"]! as NSString
```